# linux find not working from other mount points

Tags: linux, find

This works:

```
:/# find . -name *gedit*
```

It finds all given files on local disk as well as a backup disk mounted on /media/backup/root

However, change directory to /media/backup/root/ and the same command does not work:

```
:/media/backup/root# find . -name *gedit*
```

It finds nothing.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around your search term

```
:/media/backup/root# find . -name "*gedit*"
```

Comment: I had tried this, jayant. But it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to `find` (in this case `.`) tells `find` where it should start searching.

So when your current directory is `/` (The *root* of the file system) the whole system gets searched. Whereas when your current directory is `/some/other/path` only this path downward is searched.

If you want to always search the whole file system use

```
find / -name "*gedit*"
```

The quotes are important, they prevent the shell from expanding the `*`.

Comment: Ta, guntbert. I had told "find" to start from the present working directory (".") because that's where I wanted it to search from. This did not work. The point of the question is to ask why so?